# Coding 14! combinations of column Emptiness

Tags: t-sql, null, combinations, multiple-columns

I have 14 possible columns each can be either a 'Y' value OR NULL/empty string and over 37K rows of data (so manually wont work).

I need to know all the rows that have a two or more 'Y' checked. Basically each row should only have one column marked 'Yes' and if i have any columns that have more then one its an error I need to find.

```
I need to test all the possible combinations where 
columnA and columnB are not null, 
and columnA and columnC are not null, then 
columnB and columnC etc.
```

I don't want to code out all the possible combinations. is there a simpler way?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use conditional summing like this:

```
select * from your_table
where 
(
    iif(columnA ='y',1,0) 
  + iif(columnB ='y',1,0) 
  + iif(columnC ='y',1,0)
  -- etcetra for the remaining columns...
  > 1
)
```

The `where` clause above will return all rows that have more than one column with the value **y**.

Comment: How do i determine which row combinations?

Comment: Your answer is better suitable to deal with dirty data (my appraoch fully relies on `Y / empty / NULL` (according to the quesiton), which did not hold true...) +1 from my side.

Comment: @Elizabeth I guess you would need some column with an identifier, like a row number or a key.

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,ColA VARCHAR(10),ColB VARCHAR(10),ColC VARCHAR(10),ColD VARCHAR(10),ColE VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL,'Y',NULL)
                      ,(NULL,'Y',NULL,'Y',NULL)
                      ,('Y','Y','','Y','')
                      ,(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
                      ,(NULL,'',NULL,'Y',NULL)
                      ,('Y','',NULL,'Y',NULL)
                      ,('','',NULL,'Y',NULL);
SELECT * 
     ,LEN(CONCAT(ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,ColE)) CountOfY
FROM @tbl
```

The result

```
1   NULL    NULL    NULL    Y       NULL    Y       1
2   NULL    Y       NULL    Y       NULL    YY      2
3   Y       Y               Y               YYY     3
4   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL            0
5   NULL            NULL    Y       NULL    Y       1
6   Y               NULL    Y       NULL    YY      2
7                   NULL    Y       NULL    Y       1
```

This will [use `CONCAT()` (v2012+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to build a concatenated string of all columns. Then we check the length of the string. The advantage of `CONCAT` ist the implicit dealing with type casts and NULL values.

If your columns might include other values than `Y` or `NULL` / *empty string*, we still can go this route, but this would need some adaptions of course...

### Hint

You can use this to get a set of all rows and apply filters of any kind or you can shift this into a `WHERE` with `LEN(...)>1`

Comment: This is very helpful, but how do i determine which row combinations are the ones returning the problem

Comment: @Elizabeth You can use `WHERE LEN(CONCAT(ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,ColE))>1` at the end. This will put a filter on the set and return the rows with more than one `Y`

Comment: I need to know `RowA+RowB` cause a problem, `RowD + RowP` cause another. I guess this will help narrow it down but it will still require searching through all the records

Comment: @Elizabeth Don't get it... Could you please use my reduced and *stand-alone* sample to provide the expected output? Are the column names always the same? Please include the DDL of your table and some more details...

Comment: The above won't work because i'm getting values like 14, its counting the empty spaces and nulls for some reason in some cases.

Comment: @Elizabeth, You stated in your question, that all these columns can have just a `Y`, an empty string or a `NULL`. Now you are talking about *empty spaces*... Any  other value will disturb this approach - as written in the answer. You might check `WHERE LEN(REPLACE(CONCAT(ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,ColE),' ',''))>1`. This would replace blanks before `LEN()` tests the length... If this does not help you must provide more details as asked in my previous comment.

Comment: I liked the idea but I did state in my question that its a combo of NULL and empty strings. It seems problematic with empty strings in the logic. But this should help with the problem too.

Comment: @Elizabeth Don't want to be picky, but an *empty string* is a string with a length of zero... You are talking about *blank strings*...